# cv::OutOfMemoryError thrown by Mat.clone() in onCameraFrame method

Tags: android, c++, opencv

I'm new to Opencv4Android, and I'm getting an error that I can't resolve.
Basically my program relies on the onCameraFrame method that I've implemented in this way:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraView inputFrame)
{
    Mat m = inputFrame.rgba().clone();
    //Do some stuff
    return m;
}
```

The program seems to work fine, but after it has processed some frames it stops and returns these errors:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(9841): at org.opencv.core.Mat.clone(Mat.java:834)
E/AndroidRuntime(9841): at it.unive.featuretracking.FeatureTrackingTestActivity.onCameraFrame(FeatureTrackingTestActivity.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(9841): at org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.deliverAndDrawFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:387)
E/AndroidRuntime(9841): at org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView$CameraWorker.run(JavaCameraView.java:328)
E/AndroidRuntime(9841): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Moreover I've printed the exception message thrown by `Mat.clone()`

```
E/Error(16954): cv::Exception: /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/modules/core/src/alloc.cpp:52: error: (-4) Failed to allocate 8294404 bytes in function void* cv::OutOfMemoryError(std::size_t)
```

I think that the cause is the `Mat.clone()` method. If I have understood correctly, the buffer reaches the limit because it isn't freed in time. Am I right?
How can I fix the program?

**Edit:**
Ok I don't know if it is the correct solution but it seems that the program is working now with this code:

```
Mat m = null;  //declared as a field

...

public onCameraFrame(CvCameraView inputFrame)
{
    if (m != null)
    {
        m.release();
    }
    m = inputFrame.rgba().clone();
    //Do some stuff
    return m;
}
```

Comment: if you are using an emulator then increase the RAM and VMheap

Comment: I'm working on a Samsung tablet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are creating a new instance of Mat object on every frame received from the camera. Every time you call `Mat m = inputFrame.rgba().clone();` (onCameraFrame...) you create a new object (Mat...) which takes some memory. After a while you are bound to fill the RAM of your device.

I suggest you try to define `Mat m = new Mat();` just once in the `onCameraViewStarted` method (appears in most opencv4android tutorials) and then try `m = inputFrame.rgba().clone();` in `onCameraFrame`.

Comment: Maybe you meant to define 'm' as a field and initializing it in onCameraViewStarted? I tried this but I still get the error.

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant... 
It seems that your problem is related to that line - but because of the clone method. I dug a little deeper and it seems that clone creates a deep copy of a Mat object which means it allocates memory that must be freed later - but since you return m (and use it later) you must free it at some point by calling - m.release(). It depends on the way you implement the rest of your program and it is hard to tell if this is the right approach for you.

Comment: Why not just try: m = inputFrame.rgba(); and call m.release() on onCameraViewStopped()?

Comment: Thanks to your explanation It seems that I've found a solution. I've edited my post to include it. I tried also your method, but it doesn't work. I think I need to call m.release() every time a frame is captured, and not only when the camera has stopped.

Answer (score 0):

I had success at resolving this problem by adding `Mat.release()` to every OpenCV Matrix object at of course locations where each object was no longer needed.  I believe this is the same as the [Mat::t() Android, After give time gives out of the memory](http://code.opencv.org/issues/4262) bug.